# Laravel Mail not passing variables to blade template

Tags: php, laravel

I have two functions, the first one is working fine but the second one is not, in the second ones the variables appearing in the mail are {{$variableName}} unrendered.

I have checked as much other posts on SO as possible but no solution.

In the example below, in the first one the `$userName` correctly loads in the mail, whereas in the second one all variables show up as the variable name with the dollar sign.

I can confirm the `$data` variable is correct, and mails are even correctly sending using data from that variable.

```
public function workingMail($emailAddress,$userName) {
    $message = '';
    \Mail::send('workingtemplate', [
        'userName' => $userName
    ], function ($message) use ($emailAddress) {
        $message->from($this->fromAddress, $this->$this->fromAddressName);
        $message->to($emailAddress);
        $message->subject('Sample Subject');
    });
}

public function notWorkingMail($data) {
    $message = '';
    foreach($data['namesAndAddress'] as $person) {
        \Mail::send('notworkingtemplate', [
            'name' => $person['name'],
            'link' => $data['link'],
            'fileName' => $data['fileName'],
            'timeStamp' => $data['timeStamp'],
            'action' => $data['action'],
            'placeAddress' => $data['placeAddress']
        ], function ($message) use ($person,$data) {
            $message->from($this->fromAddress, $this->fromAddressName);
            $message->to($person['email']);
            $message->subject($data['placeAddress'].' files have been updated.');
        });
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try this: Create an array at the top of your foreach. (`$arr = ['name'=>....];`) Log it with `Log::info($arr);` to make sure it's being created correctly, then pass your created `$arr` into your send function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had forgotten to add .blade to the name of the php file. It worked perfectly as soon as I did.

Comment: You saved my life literally !